# Glide cache image on disk on background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-glide

I want to use Glide to eagerly download images and cache them on disk for a future use. I want to call this functionality from a background thread.

I've read [Glide's caching documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html), but it doesn't explain how to download the image without having an actual target right now. Then I found [this issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2419) and tried to use a similar approach, but whatever I try I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread
```

So, how can I tell Glide to cache an image from a background thread?

**EDIT:** I really want to call Glide's methods on background thread. I know that I can use Handler and other ways to offload it to UI thread, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Why don't you download ImageURLs and store it in Room DB and whenever you want, you can load the images from that DB instead.

Comment: @UmangBurman, storing images in DB is a bad idea (just like storing any other big binary objects). I could download the image, store it locally and keep the local URI, but that would amount to reinventing the wheel. First I want to know whether Glide can do that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
GlideApp.with(context)
    .downloadOnly()
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA) // Cache resource before it's decoded
    .load(url)
    .submit(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
    .get() // Called on background thread
```

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for. It even blocks the thread which is great. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If want to load images in **cache for future use in background thread** then Glide have this functionality

here how you can do this

```
 //here i passing application context so our glide tie itself with application lifecycle

FutureTarget<File> future = Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).downloadOnly().load("your_image_url").submit();
```

now if you want to retrieve the saved path that you want to store in your DB then you can do

```
File file = future.get();
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

you can also do this in just one line returning a path string like this

```
String path = Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).downloadOnly().load("your_image_url").submit().get().getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Thanks for your very elaborate answer. It's correct, but I decided to accept another answer because it turns out that using `DATA` cache strategy is mandatory in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Did I get the question right?

```
private class update extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) // Saves all image resolution
        .centerCrop()
        .priority(Priority.HIGH)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.null_image_profile)
        .error(R.drawable.null_image_profile);

    Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl)
        .apply(options);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        //finish
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. I don't have `profileImage`, but even if I would have one, call to `into` on background thread throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

> You must call this method **on the main thread**

Wherever you call a method to use `Glide` or doing something from background, run inside:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

              // Here, use glide or do your things on UiThread

            }
        });
```

To use it inside the main thread and then error should be gone.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked. I'm interested in calling Glide's methods from background thread, not jumping back to UI thread.

Comment: Correct! I just saw your edit. But, the point is, **`Glide` effects on UI** since it's an image loading library. So, no matter what you wanna achieve, it will throws exceptions like now.